# Counting values within multidimensional arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a large array where I basically need to count the number of uniques:
[example array](http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?0fed0a0438e9c791#AomjzLQVV6e9Ex8s1qGaB6QIGkLOUfnlUwSgZxQ2HUM=)

The end result I am looking for something like

```
$result = array(
    'A3D5' => array('P2' => 1, 'P3' => 1, 'P4' => 1, 'total' => 3),
    'AE5S' => array('P4' => 1, 'total' => 1)
);
```

I've tried foreaching through but can't seem to figure out how to sort them into another key, something like `$zone = "P{$array['zone']}"; $result[$zone][$prestige]++` or seems to kind of not work or just error.

Comment: There is no 'A35S' in your example array.

Comment: And 'AE5S' has a 'prestige' value of 2, not 'P4'.

Comment: Fixed, and I am looking to count the number of occurrances of a certain value, not the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    "denizen" => array
        (
            "prestige" => 2,
            "zone" => "A3D5",
            "scope_frag" => 765
        ),

    "생각" => array
        (
            "prestige" => 4,
            "zone" => "A3D5",
            "scope_frag" => 135
        ),

    "Ryans" => array
        (
            "prestige" => 3,
            "zone" => "A3D5",
            "scope_frag" => 78
        ),

    "지적인" => array
        (
            "prestige" => 2,
            "zone" => "AE5S",
            "scope_frag" => 481
        )
);
foreach ($array as $group) {
    $zones[$group["zone"]][] = $group["prestige"];
}
foreach ($zones as $name => $zone) {
    $total = count($zone);
    foreach ($zone as $prestige) {
        $result[$name]["P".$prestige] += 1;
    }
    ksort($result[$name]);
    $result[$name]["total"] = $total;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```